# String format for currency(negative value formatted with braces)

Tags: currency, string.format

When we convert like `String.Format("{0:C}", 126.45)` it returns $126.45

but if we convert like  `String.Format("{0:C}", -126.45)` it returns ($126.45)

Why negative conversion return braces?
What to do if we don't want this braces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you try something like:

```
String.Format("{0:$#,##0.00}", -126.45)
```

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) here a format of "{0:C1}" or "{0:C2}" should work, but for some strange reason it is not..

Another approach could be setting the CultureInfo:

```
CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
string s = string.Format(culture, "{0:c}", -126.45);
```

Reference [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/257565-Formatting-Currecny-to-use-instead-of--for-negatives-c/)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** Here is best solution if you get after formate this kind of value (-300)

```
extension Double {
static let twoFractionDigits: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
    formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true

    return formatter
}()
var formatted: String {
    return Double.twoFractionDigits.string(for: self) ?? ""
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the en-US locale, parentheses are used to denote negative values.  Visually scanning a long column of numbers, many people find it easier to see the negatives.  Often it's the negative values that are of most concern (oops!  my checking account balance is overdrawn).

To get different formatting behavior, you can change your locale, or you can change your [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) to something like F.

Answer (score 0):

It does parentheses, because that's the standard on whatever `CultureInfo` you are using.

Never done it myself but the make up of the format is controlled by the current `NumberFormatInfo` instance.

If you figure it out, answer your own question, and I'll plus you